# How To fix "Access to the path is denied"

Tags: c#

[image]

```
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string computername = Environment.MachineName;
            string mainpath = "C:/Users/"+computername+"/Documents/Folder1";
            if (!Directory.Exists(mainpath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mainpath);
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

How To fix "Access to the path is denied"?

Comment: What is the OS ??

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the computer account's folder in the first place? You can't modify another user's folder unless you're either given permissions explicitly or you're an administrator on the machine (which does have permissions)

Comment: Does that path exists? Because I think you should be looking for the UserName of the user and not the MachineName.

Comment: You don't need to check if the directory exists before you try to create it. `CreateDirectory` is a no-op if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 2):

##### Problem

Your code is trying to create a new folder with your machine's name (DESKTOP-DUP73VB) in the `C:\Users` directory (and then the additional folders `Documents` and `Folder1`).

Creating new folders in `C:\Users` requires admin privileges which is why you see the UnauthorizedAccessException.

##### Solution A

If you are trying to create a folder **in your user profile**, you should replace `Environment.MachineName` with `Environment.UserName`.

Or better yet, use `"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Folder1"` as path instead of hardcoding `C:\Users\...`.

If you want a really robust solution with the minimum amount of hardcoded directory names, you could also use the following:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Folder1")
```

##### Solution B

If you are trying to create a folder in the **"all users" profile**, the correct path is `C:\Users\Public\Documents\...` instead.

<s>However, creating files and folders in this path requires admin privileges as well by default.</s>
EDIT: My mistake, only some folders in the "all users" profile are protected, for example the Desktop folder. It looks like any user can create new files and folders in the public Documents folder.

You could get the correct path in code as follows:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments), "Folder1")
```